How do I say “I’m going from…” in Chinese
Is it correct to say “我从上班” for ”I’m going (leaving) from work” when someone asks “where are you?”
and ”我从上班到家” when saying “ I’m going from work to home”

No.First I think "I’m going (leaving) from work" is not a very clear answer to "where are you?”  I suppose you mean "I'll get home from work."
So the answer should be "我将从公司回家" or "我马上回家",将 or 将要 mean going to
"从" means "from" only.
In English "from" sometimes carries the meaning of "leaving from" in the single word.
But in Chinese, "从" never naturally carry the meaning of "leave"

The character 从 cannot be used to express "leave," but only "from."  It needs to be used with an appropriate verb to form a complete expression.  The character 从, when used as a preposition or coverb, must generally be followed by an expression of location or time.  Neither 上班 nor 班 are locations, and neither actually means "work."
As an expression, 上班 is often the equivalent of "start/go to work"; however, its literal meaning is more like "start a shift" or "go on duty at the work unit."  The expression 下班 is the opposite and means "to get off work." These are activities that are associated with a location but do not directly express location by themselves and do not really express movement from one place to another.
Chinese is generally more restrictive than English in what it allows as expressions of location and generally does not allow activities, events, or people to express location directly.  For instance, in Chinese, you cannot "go to a movie," but must "go to see a movie" or "go to a movie theater."
In talking about going to or leaving work, Chinese generally uses 上班 or 下班; however, if you need to emphasize physical location, you need a verb like 离开 and an expression of location like 公司 that are more specific.  Note, however, that 离开 is transitive and is not used with 从.  To say "leave work" using this verb, you would just say 离开公司 without using 从 at all.

我从上班到家

If you replace 上班 with 公司 (i.e., 我从公司到家), this expression becomes possible but is incomplete.  The character 到 is not used be itself to mean "go to" in modern Chinese.  "Go to" is usually expressed by 到 + [location] + 去.  Also, "go home" is usually expressed by 回家 and not literally by 到家去. If you say 我从公司到家去, you get a grammatically correct expression that could conceivably translate "I am going home from work"; however, both the English and Chinese are very unlikely ways to answer the question "Where are you?" There are other much more likely expressions, depending on the context of the conversation and what you want to convey.

從 - "from"; 從A到B = "from A to B".
Q: Where are you (now)? - 你(現在)在那裡?
A: I am about to leave work and get ready to go home. It takes about 40 minutes to drive from work to home - 我正要離開公司準備回家. 從公司到家裡開車大約要40分鐘.
Other possible answers:

I am at work but am ready to go home now. - 我在公司正準備回家

I am off work already and about to go home now. - 我已經下班了正準備回家.

I am off work and on my way home now. - 我已經下班了正在回家路上.


How to say "go (to) B from A"?

I am going to the airport(B) directly from home(A). - 我"從家裡(from home)"直接"去機場(going to the airport)".

I am going home(B) directly from the airport(A). - 我"從機場from the airport"直接"回家(going home)"



"I'm going from work" could be correct in the right context, but not if you mean "I'm leaving work".  If I ask you, "Are you going to the cafe later?" You might reply, "Yes, I'm going (there straight) from work.
你晚些时候去咖啡馆吗?
Are you going to the cafe later?
是的，我下班后（直接）去那里。
Yeah, I'm going there straight from work.
But otherwise:
I am leaving work now.
我现在下班。
